# Firebase Push Notification Doesn't Replace the Exisiting Notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, firebase-notifications

I'm creating a chat application which send push notifications using firebase
as my chatApp goes in background and send push notifications in row it generate new notification everytime as i have created a unique notification id for it.

I want to group to notification or update the existing one.

[Image that Doesnt Group Firebase Push Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouMIi.jpg)

Here is my Code of Firebase Messaging Service

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public int no_of_messages = 0,i=0;
private int notify_id= 12121; // this was my actual code

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    showNotification(remoteMessage, remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    no_of_messages++;
}

private void showNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage, String message) {


Intent i = new Intent(remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction());
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Uri notification = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.coin);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (no_of_messages == 0) {
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle())
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.auto)
                .setSound(notification)
                .setNumber(no_of_messages)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    } else {
        builder.setContentTitle(no_of_messages+"New Messages")
                .setNumber(no_of_messages)
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(notify_id, builder.build());

   }
}
```

PHP script 
function for sending to FCM

```
function send_to_fcm($token,$title,$message,$click_action){

    $body = array("to"=>$token."", 
                  "notification" => array(
                        "title" => $title ,
                        "body"=> $message,
                        "click_action"=>$click_action,
                        'vibrate'   => 1,
                        'sound'     => "coin",
                        'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
                        'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
                        )
                );
    echo json_encode($body);
    $header = array("Authorization:key=".FCM_SERVER_KEY,"Content-type:application/json");

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  FCM_PATH);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));

    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch); 
    //echo $buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For update existing notification **notify_id** must be same as older one.
if notify_id will be changed it will generate new notification will not update existing one.

I am using below code for check message contain data payload or notification payload (notification payload contains notification from PHP)

```html
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
            message = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");
            image = remoteMessage.getData().get("icon");
}

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
            message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            image = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
}
```

Comment: yh you are right !! i already did that but !! when app goes in background it generates new notifications as firebase handles notification in background how to fix that

Comment: If you are sending notification only via firebase you cant handle notification in background.. for made it possible user custom notification using payload.. firebase doesn't allow you to change notification when app in backgroud. If you will use send notification code from PHP or any other platform you can handle notification in background

Comment: i am using PHP platform to send notificaiton check out my php script 
still aint working out

Comment: **Thank You Jenisha** that was a great help.. **: )**

Comment: There You GO **Ms.CEO** 
Keep Coding Keep Helping

Answer (score 1):

In order to replace the `notify_id` must be same as previous. Use some constant value.

Comment: definetly !! i already did that but !! when app goes in background it generates new notifications as firebase handles notification in background how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

**[ FIX ]**

So there was a problem in PHP script

I Used **"notification"** as parameter for sending Notification
i Changed it to **"data"** which solved my problem

here is PHP Script

```
 $body = array("to"=>$token."", 
              "data" => array(
                    "title" => $title ,
                    "body"=> $message,
                    "click_action"=>$click_action,
                    'vibrate'   => 1,
                    'sound'     => "coin",
                    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
                    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
                    )
            );
```

and

MyFirebaseMessangingClass

```
 Intent i = new Intent(remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action"));
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    Uri notification = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.coin);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    if (no_of_messages == 0) {
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("body"))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(notification)
                .setNumber(no_of_messages)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        no_of_messages++;
    } else {
        builder.setContentTitle("Eaziche | "+no_of_messages+" New Messages")
                .setNumber(no_of_messages)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setSound(notification)
                .setNumber(no_of_messages)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"));
    }

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(notify_id, builder.build()); // notify_id = 12121
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other services, netmera service can be used with firebase with simple method in netmera, please review the following block:

```
public class PushMessaging extends FirebaseMessagingService {

  @Override
  public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)

       if (Netmera.isNetmeraRemoteMessage(remoteMessage)) {

          Netmera.onNetmeraPushMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        } else {
            //another operations
        }
   }


 @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);

           Netmera.onNetmeraNewToken(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34713140)